# How to center and manipulate the size of a ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[I can't change the ListView's position, I would like it to be more in the center. I'll put it on another screen, this is just a test.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfzT5.png)

[I want to put multiple item names inside a ListView on the same screen without overflowing the screen space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3LaE.png)

Comment: Please include codes here.. also what's checar caixa in the screenshot? List tile?

Comment: You can move the ListView to center by giving it horizontal padding. Or you can use Column instead of ListView and wrap Column in SingleChildScrollView. To do this, you use the CrossAxisAlignment.center property of Column.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your questions, and based on what I understood.

> You want to make your ListView in the middle of the screen Right!!
> To do that, you simply have to wrap your Listview in a **Center Widget** as a child of your container (Pretty easy :) )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).